# How to program in C# with TextMate as my IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, mono, textmate

Yes, I know there is [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).  But what if I want to use [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) instead?

So my question here is aimed at the .Net developer who has developed some C# applications using Textmate.  I'm curious as to what their process/workflow is with this setup.

- What is the best C# bundle out there for syntax/language grammar?
- How do you build your project? (easy to build app for 2.0, 3.0, and/or 3.5 framework?)
- Can you easily start a C# application in Visual Studio, and then continue to use TextMate in it's place?

Are there too many pitfalls here in thinking I could do this, and [am I just taking crazy pills](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx_ZU-qRD1Q)?

Comment: if it's just the theme you want:
http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/10/17/textmate-theme-for-visual-studio-take-2/

Comment: Funny you mention that, I do use that for Visual Studio, with the Consolas font: http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=22E69AE4-7E40-4807-8A86-B3D36FAB68D3&displaylang=en. :)  Good to bring it up though, for those who haven't seen it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be honest I still do my actual C# building through a Virtual Machine running Windows, but I edit anything that I can through Textmate.
I use the [ASP.Net VB.Net](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/ASP_vb_NET.tmbundle/) tmbundle and I actually just discovered a [C#](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/C%23.tmbundle/) tmbundle.

I am planning on switching to building in MonoDevelop if I can, but right now I work with teams that only use Windows so to be safe I'm still stuck building in Visual Studio.

Comment: damn c# bundle link is broken... Googling doesn't seem to give me anything. Do you know if it's still available?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle
or this: http://drp.ly/Vdjcm

I have tried neither of them.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I found it along the way when trying to find a C# bundle for TextMate.

The C# bundle has moved from the macromoates svn repos into github at https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle.

Hopefully this helps other people looking for the bundle.